# Return value from controller to code behind blazor page

Tags: controller, blazor, blazor-server-side, code-behind

I have the following controller:

```
        // Multiple files upload
        [HttpPost("upload/multiple")]
        public IActionResult Multiple(IFormFile[] files)
        {
            try
            {
                // Put your code here

                foreach (var file in files)
                {
                    var content = new MemoryStream();
                    file.CopyTo(content);
                    content.Position = 0;

                    var contentType = ContentType.Parse(file.ContentType);
                    var part = new MimePart(contentType.MimeType)
                    {
                        FileName = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName),
                        ContentTransferEncoding = ContentEncoding.Base64,
                        Content = new MimeContent(content),
                    };
                    
                }
                return StatusCode(200);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return StatusCode(500, ex.Message);
            }
        }
```

and the following code behind for a blazor page

```
       private async Task SendMail()
        {
            try
            { 
                // create email message
                var email = new MimeMessage();
                email.From.Add(MailboxAddress.Parse(sender));
                email.To.Add(MailboxAddress.Parse(receiver));
                email.Subject = emailSubject;
                //email.Body = new TextPart(TextFormat.Html) { Text = emailMessage};
                var multipart = new Multipart("mixed");
                multipart.Add(new TextPart(TextFormat.Html) { Text = emailMessage });
                multipart.Add(part);
                email.Body = multipart;
                // send email
                using var smtp = new SmtpClient();
                smtp.Connect(outgoingServer, outgoingPort, SecureSocketOptions.Auto);
                smtp.Authenticate(userName, userPassword);
                smtp.Send(email);
                smtp.Disconnect(true);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                NotificationService.Notify(NotificationSeverity.Error, "Send Email Error!", ex.Message, 7000);
            }
        }
```

There is a variable in the controller called part (encodes files as mimeparts) that I need to access from the codebehind.

multipart.Add(part);

how do I get this value from the controller to the code???

Comment: are you calling `SendMail()` after you do a `httppost` request?

Comment: also, make a `return_object` and `return` that `part values` with other information you are already returning.